# Service-hosted WCF behind the load balancer

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, hostname

I have 3 servers and a load balancer. Servers names are:

- server-11
- server-12
- server-13

And the balancer's name is:

- server-01

Everything works in the **intra**net, in my local network.

I have **IIS**-hosted websites at servers, and I access them like that: http://server-01:12321 for example, and it forwards me to some of the server.

Now I need to set up an existing WCF service with **WSHttpBinding** the same way - install it at all 3 servers (already done) and access it via load balancer. The problem is: my WCF-service is not hosted in **IIS**, it is hosted in **windows service**.

Another problem is: I want to have an url for that WCF-service like http://myservice, so when I open it, it will get me to the http://server-01:80 and then load balancer will forward it to some server.

Is it possible? I believe I should set some DNS record somewhere? And what settings are to be made in the load balancer? And what changes should I make in the WCF-service itself?

Another difficulty is that 80 port is already occupied (with several websites hostnames), so I have to use hostname (http://myservice). To be clear: in **IIS** I can set a hostname for the website, but how to do this with WCF-service, that is hosted in **windows service**?

Comment: What are you asking? It doesn't matter to the load balancer how the service is hosted or what it does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well, ok, I guess... But how to set hostname to that service, so I can address it like http://myservice?